# React Native - json - [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'key.time.date')]

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am writing a React Native app which fetchs data from server. I need to receive json and return only some received objects (the ones with date later than the current one). The problem occurs midway.
Here is my code

```
import {serverURL} from '../assets/config/server'



export const getEventsByRegion = (region) => {
    let events;
    let url = `${serverURL}events/eventList`
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => { 
        return response.json();})
    .then(responseData => {
        events = responseData;
        })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("fetch error" + err);
    })
    .then( () =>
        {
            if(events){
                events = Object.values(events).filter((key) => {
                    console.log(key)
                    return ((key.region[0] === region) )
                })
            } else 
            events = null;
            if(events){
                events = Object.values(events).filter((key) => {
                    console.log(key.name, key.time)
                    console.log(key.time.date)
                    return (toSimpleDate(new Date(key.time.date)) >= toSimpleDate(new Date())) 
                })
            } 
            
            if(events !== undefined) {
                return events; 
            }

        }
        
    );
}


  toSimpleDate = (date) => {
    return date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  }
```

And here is my console.log() output

```
//first output - full
//1
Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "607e06dd5195440015e95ed6",
  "description": "",
  "geoLocation": Object {
    "_id": "607e06dd5195440015e95ed7",
    "geometry": Object {
      "coordinates": Array [
        null,
        null,
      ],
      "type": "Point",
    },
    "type": "Feature",
  },
  "inBus": true,
  "name": "Test event 1",
  "region": Array [
    "Region1",
  ],
  "time": Object {
    "date": "2021-04-19T22:37:37.055Z",
    "timeFrom": "2021-04-19T22:37:37.055Z",
    "timeTo": "2021-04-20T10:37:00.000Z",
  },
}

//2
Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "60911a388446fe0015c8f7e0",
  "description": "test description",
  "geoLocation": Object {
    "_id": "60911a388446fe0015c8f7e1",
    "geometry": Object {
      "coordinates": Array [
        null,
        null,
      ],
      "type": "Point",
    },
    "type": "Feature",
  },
  "inBus": false,
  "name": "Test event 2",
  "region": Array [
    "Region1",
  ],
  "time": Object {
    "date": "2021-05-26T09:54:00.000Z",
    "timeFrom": "2021-05-04T08:00:15.410Z",
    "timeTo": "2021-05-04T12:25:15.410Z",
  },
}
//second output - a part only
//1
Test event 1 Object {
  "date": "2021-01-01T12:41:00.000Z",
  "timeFrom": "2020-12-27T11:41:48.610Z",
  "timeTo": "2020-12-27T12:41:48.610Z",
}

2021-01-01T12:41:00.000Z

//2
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'key.time.date')]
//
```

As you can see, it refuses to read key.time.date field (the example doesn't show it, but there is no problem with key.time nor with key.name). The origin of data is the same and I can't find the problem with structure.

Please help